# JavaEE and OSGI:How to get BeanManager for certain osgi bundle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, cdi

As I understand right every osgi bundle has its own cdi container. So I have the following situation - I have two bundles: A and B. Bundles are deployed in glassfish4. In bundle A I have cdi beans. In bundle B I don't have beans.xml -> no cdi container for the bundle B is created.

In bundle B I have a reference to bundle A (Bundle bundleA).  How can I get in bundle B reference to bundle A cdi container. My current solution (in bundle B):

```
BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
```

throws exception:

```
StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001328: Unable to identify the correct BeanManager. The calling class com.temp.MyClass is not placed in bean archive
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI.unsatisfiedBeanManager(SimpleCDI.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.weld.GlassFishWeldProvider$GlassFishEnhancedWeld.unsatisfiedBeanManager(GlassFishWeldProvider.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI$ClassNameToBeanManager.findBeanManager(SimpleCDI.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI$ClassNameToBeanManager.load(SimpleCDI.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI$ClassNameToBeanManager.load(SimpleCDI.java:40)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4884)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI.getBeanManager(SimpleCDI.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI.getBeanManager(SimpleCDI.java:38)
```

Comment: First sentence is confusing: "As I understand right every osgi bundle has its own cdi container". NONE of the bundles I've ever written has its own CDI container (and I have written quite a lot...).

Comment: For what it's worth -- I know nothing about CDI and don't really want to -- it sounds like what you're trying to do should be solved with OSGi Services.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett Please, read carefully. The question is about javaee and glassfish.

Comment: What makes you think I didn't read carefully? The sentence is still definitively wrong. Maybe you meant to say "every OSGi *deployed to Glassfish* has its own CDI container". I still don't know whether that's true but it's likely a lot closer to the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();` is the correct way to obtain a `BeanManager` for current bean archive. E.g. the bean archive to which the class where you invoke this belongs. That would be `bundle B` in your case. And you do not have a `beans.xml` there hence the exception.

> As I understand right every osgi bundle has its own cdi container.

I am not much familiar with OSGI but from Weld perspective that would work. Weld sees any form of archive (jar, war, ...) as bean archive and for one bean archive you have one manager.

If you want a reference to BM from `bundle A`, obtain it there and expose a getter I suppose. The point is you need to invoke `getBeanManager()` from the actual archive it belongs to.

Maybe if you elaborated on what do you aim to achieve with that BM, I might help you further. Generaly speaking I would refrain from obtaining references to BMs from other archives. You can always have an exposed API and let the original archive deliver the services to you.

Comment: Maybe you know - is there a way to getBeanManager by class which belong to certain archive?

Comment: I don't think so. Generally speaking you are not supposed to obtain a manager of other archive. Imagine you were using a 3rd party library and this would allow you to mess up with it even though it is not even your code.

Comment: For cross-bundle sharing of objects you should be using OSGi Services.